# In TOC: How to hide numbering of \section in \subsection?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, subsection, depth

Does anyone know how I can make it so that no numbering of the parent heading appears in the table listing?
Output of my current minimal example

```
I
 I.1
 I.2
 I.3
 I.4
   I.4.1
   I.4.2
II
```

But i want the following format:

```
I
 1
 2
 3
 4
  1
  2
II
```

Here is an minimal example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,german,titlepage,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} \setcounter{tocdepth}{3} \pagestyle{headings} \raggedbottom
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
    \end{titlepage}
    
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \section{Test1}
    \clearpage
    \subsection{Test2}
    \clearpage
    \subsection{Test2}
    \clearpage
    \subsection{Test2}
    \clearpage
    \subsection{Test2}
    \clearpage
    \subsubsection{Test3}
    \clearpage
    \subsubsection{Test3}
    \clearpage
    \section{Test1}
    \clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Just add to preamble `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\arabic{subsubsection}}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution which doesn't require the loading of any particular LaTeX packages. It displays the "full" (composite) subsection and subsection numbers in sectioning headers and in any cross-references to subsection and subsubsection headers, but shows only the simple "numbers" (or letters) in the Table of Contents.

[image]

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\pagestyle{headings} 

% Choose unique numbering styles:
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\alph{subsubsection}}

% Use method proposed in "The LaTeX Companion", 2nd ed., to
% determine how the section-like counters are displayed in
% sectioning headers:
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\space}%default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%  enable individual control 
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{%     subsection
   \thesection.\thesubsection\space} 
\newcommand\subsubsection@cntformat{%  subsubsection
   \thesection.\thesubsection.\thesubsubsection\space}
\makeatother

% Display section and subsection numbers in cross-references
% to subsections and subsubsections
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{\thesection.}
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{\thesection.\thesubsection.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{Test I} \label{sec:aaa}
\clearpage
\subsection{Test I1}
\clearpage
\subsection{Test I2} \label{sec:bbb}
\clearpage
\subsection{Test I3}
\clearpage
\subsection{Test I4}
\clearpage
\subsubsection{Test I4a}
\clearpage
\subsubsection{Test I4b} \label{sec:ccc}

\clearpage
\section{Test II}
Cross-references to sections \ref{sec:aaa}, \ref{sec:bbb}, 
and \ref{sec:ccc}.

\end{document}
```